# How do you create a MVC project with Individual Authentication using Visual Studio Code CLI

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a new mvc project using Visual Studio Code last night with individual user authentication using the built in CLI. I was reading through Microsoft's web document tutorial and noticed I had an old .net core sdk 3.2 I think. So I installed 5.0 tonight then tried to make a new project using the same CLI command and I'm getting a weird error about third party templates

CLI Command:
dotnet new mvc -au Individual -o MyProject

**Error:**
This template contains technologies from parties other than Microsoft, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/5.0-third-party-notices for details.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\Users\user\documents\test2\test2.csproj...
Determining projects to restore...
Restored C:\Users\user\documents\test2\test2.csproj (in 254 ms).
Restore succeeded.

Edit:
So doing more testing it appears my mvc template is broken? I get this anytime I use dotnet new mvc

Answer (score 0):

To have individual user authentication, I think the best solution will be `IdentityServer4`.

The explanation of how to implement this method is very long, but I will introduce you to some of the best links:

[IdentityServer4 main website](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[A full source code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/ionepaul/dotnet-api-with-identity-server)

[Step by step implementing IdentityServer4](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4)